# How to set Background image of button

Tags: ios, button, background

I have a question and I didn't find an answer on it yet. I would like to know how to set the background image of a button in your code. I would like to use a value to change the background.
For example: `if (value == one) { set background of button code}`

I have two backgrounds but when you give a code you can use buttonimage1.png, buttonimage2.png.

Thnx

Comment: Please edit your post to include more details on what the problem is, and what you've tried. As it stands, it is very unclear what you're asking.

Comment: -1 *This question does not show any [research](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html)*.

Answer (score 0):

First you should add IBOutlet for your button, example:

```
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIButton *bttn;
```

next, using this outlet you can change background:

```
 if (value == one) {
    [self.bttn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonimage1.png"]
                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
} else {
    [self.bttn setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonimage2.png"]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

that's all

Comment: The outlet is completely unrelated to the question. This may be a button that was created programmatically, or the OP might find the button using a tag. It's really not right to claim that the OP *should* create an outlet, and having an outlet doesn't change the relevant part of the answer at all.